# WhenEvent in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, version-9

How come this doesn't work as I intended?

```
s[{x0_, y0_}, a_, v_] := NDSolveValue[{
   x'[t] == vx[t], WhenEvent[x[t] > 0, vx[t] -> -vx[t]],
   y'[t] == vy[t] - t, WhenEvent[y[t] < 0, vy[t] -> -vy[t]],
   x[0] == x0, vx[0] == v Cos@a,
   y[0] == y0, vy[0] == v Sin@a},
  {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 10},
  DiscreteVariables -> {vx, vy}]
```

Simulating falling and bouncing of a 2D mass point.

```
With[{r0 = {-5, 7}},
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate@s[r0, -.9, 2],
  {t, 0, 10},
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}},
  Epilog -> {Point@r0}]]
```

[image: Fall]

I can't understand why it doesn't bounce on the x-axis first, and what *does* happen there anyway? Event `x[t]>0` works fine.

---

[image: bouncing ball]

Following help I started with lowering the order of equations (and so doubling the number of variables). Here I wrote the equations in a more familiar 2nd order; everything works as expected. I put the function below in a tiny loop which bisected the right initial velocity `v0` that returns the ball in its starting position.

Could this be done within `NDSolve`? I looked Wolfram tutorial for *Boundary Value Problems* but haven't been able to figure it out.

```
sstop[{x0_, y0_}, a_, v0_] := NDSolveValue[{
    x''[t] == 0, WhenEvent[x[t] > 0, x'[t] -> -x'[t]],
    y''[t] == -1, WhenEvent[y[t] < 0, y'[t] -> -y'[t]],
    WhenEvent[x[t] < x0, Sow[{t, y[t]}]; "StopIntegration"],
    x[0] == x0, x'[0] == v0 Cos[a],
    y[0] == y0, y'[0] == v0 Sin[a]},
   {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 20}] // Reap
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the WhenEvent for x[t]>0? Is it the other When Event still ignored?

Comment: Try this `WhenEvent[{x[t] > 0, y[t] <0}, If[x[t]>0,vx[t] -> -vx[t],vy[t] -> -vy[t] ]]`
I think you can have only one WhenEvent included.

Comment: @Spawn1701D Gee, now the same "refraction" occurs at y-axis as well.

Comment: I read the manual and I thing that if you have more than one WhenEvents you have to put them in a list, e.g { WhenEvent[x[t] > 0, vx[t] -> -vx[t]], WhenEvent[y[t] < 0, vy[t] -> -vy[t]]}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here you have a bouncing ball simulation using WithEvents[]:

```
s[{x0_, y0_}, a_, v_] := NDSolveValue[
   {
    y''[t] == -1,
    x'[t] == vx[t],
    y[0] == y0,
    x[0] == x0,
    y'[0] == v Sin@a,
    vx[0] == v Cos@a,
    vy[0] == v Sin@a,
    WhenEvent[y[t] < 0, y'[t] -> - y'[t]],
    WhenEvent[x[t] > 0, vx[t] -> -vx[t]]},
   {x, y}, {t, 0, 8},
   DiscreteVariables -> {vx, vy}] ;

With[{r0 = {-1, 1}},
 ParametricPlot[Through[s[r0, 1, 1][u]], {u, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Epilog -> {Point@r0}]]
```

[image]

Comment: That is weird. If anything, `vy` picks up, and what does `vx[t] -> - 3 vx[t]` *mean*? I'm running a physical system here! :)

Comment: Thanks. I made a conceptual mistake, I can now understand what was going on above.