# Replicating off-the-shelf ODE solvers

Tags: differential-equations, neural-networks

I've been working through some literature on ODEs and keep coming across the below pseudo-code expression and am having trouble interpreting it for use in the Wolfram Language. I feel like I've solved many initial value problems over the years with `NDSolve`, but now think I need some help from someone who works with ODEs in a more robust capacity to describe the differences.

[image]

The above is from [here](https://rkevingibson.github.io/blog/neural-networks-as-ordinary-differential-equations/) which states that `h(t0)` is the initial state of the system, `G` is the function that defines the system. `t0` & `t1` are the start and end times and `Theta` is the parameters. (Pytorch also has an [implementation](https://github.com/rtqichen/torchdiffeq) I've been looking at).

As I researched ways to understand the parameters, I kept coming up with pseudo-code examples using `ODESolve`. Should I be using a different MMA function? Maybe there is an option I'm not understanding? What's the most straightforward way to think about this pseudo-code example in Mathematica?

Comment: In MA $\theta$-parameters are embedded in $G$. That is the only difference. However, there are several things that come as options to `NDSolve` that can be regarded as parameters $\theta$: `AccuracyGoal`, `PrecisionGoal` and `WhenEvent` .

Comment: This is relevant to my previous comment https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23102/whenevent-in-ndsolve

Comment: To expand on @yarchik: I think it's something like `NDSolve[{h'[t] == G[h[t], t, theta], h[t0] == h0}, {t, t0, t1}, opts...]`, where `h0` is ${\bf h}(t_0)$. The parameters `theta` have to be specified numerically and are updated after each `NDSolve` call, to minimize the loss function I suppose. But I'll leave that for folks who do machine learning to explain.

Comment: There's also `ParametricNDSolve`, which explicitly separates out parameters $\theta$.

Comment: @ChrisK Good rec. It also has the option, `Method -> {"ParametricSensitivity" -> "AdjointSensitivity"}`, which might do what the paper describes. I have yet to find a discussion of `"ParametricSensitivity"`, other than a few scattered examples. There is probably more than is shown in them, judging by the error messages I get if I use `"ParametricSensitivity" -> Foo` and `"ParametricSensitivity" -> {1, 0}` in `Method` option to `ParametricNDSolve`. Would you happen to know of more complete documentation of `"ParametricSensitivity"`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sorry, you already know more than I do about it